# Is there a currently maintained way to use Qt Mobility with PyQt?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, maps, qt-mobility

I downloaded [an example](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-mobility/source/811810631c67d0e0ea91c06d974406221c1b75c5:examples/location/mapviewer.py) from PySide QtMobility examples, and it looks like, at least some time in the past, there was support for QtMobility in PySide.

When I tried to run the script, it's no surprise there is no module to import (because of course I haven't installed nothing yet)

```
from QtMobility.Location import QGeoServiceProvider, QGraphicsGeoMap, QGeoMapPolylineObject
from QtMobility.Location import QGeoCoordinate, QGeoMapRectangleObject, QGeoMapPixmapObject
from QtMobility.Location import QGeoMapPolygonObject, QGeoMapCircleObject, QGeoMapTextObject
from QtMobility.Location import QGeoMapRouteObject, QGeoRouteRequest

>> ImportError: No module named QtMobility.Location
```

I didn't find any `setup.py` or other way to even try to install this module, and anyway I suspect it is rather old (last commit by the end of 2011).

So, questions are:

- Shoud I try to use this PyQt mobility library? How difficult would it be to make it work with current PyQt/PySide?
- Is there any ongoing development in this field? (mapping SDKs for PyQt/PySide)?

I am already trying to make some progress with SlippyMap class taken from [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/69377628/), and I'm think about porting it to Qt Graphics Framework (with MapView and MapScene classes, and layers, and draggable polyline nodes, and stuff) but honestly, it would be much better to use something already existing with possible.